# Delete last node of single linked list using tail pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm creating a singly linked list in C which has head and tail pointers where the head pointer points to starting node of SLL and tail pointer points to the last node of SLL. I don't want to traverse till the end of the list using the head pointer to delete the node. Is there a way so that I can use the tail pointer to delete the last element of SLL?

Following is node addition function. head and tail are initiated NULL.

```
void add_node_last(Node** head, Node** tail, int data) {

    Node* new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    new_node -> data = data;
    new_node -> ptr  = NULL;

    if(*head == NULL && *tail == NULL) {
        *head = new_node;
        *tail = new_node;
        return;
    }

    (*tail) -> ptr = new_node;

    *tail = new_node;

}
```

To delete the first node, the following function is used:

```
void del_first(Node **head) {
    if(*head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    *head = (*head) -> ptr;
    free(*head);
}
```

Comment: BTW `free(*head);` is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What is correct statement then?

Comment: `Node *temp = *head; *head = (*head) -> ptr; free(temp);` Also if become `*head == NULL` then Need set tail to NULL.

Comment: Can u elaborate why its wrong?

Comment: After updating it destroys the list.

Comment: Actually, the code is working fine with this function. It's not destroying list.

Comment: E.g  a list : A => B => C, `*head` point to A , `*head = (*head) -> ptr;` ==> now `*head` point to B, ==>  `free(*head);` : release node `B`. The list is not broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can free the node's memory, but only once. After the first removal, your tail pointer, and the `ptr` of the second to last node, will be invalid pointers. In order to make sure both pointers are always correct you either need to traverse the entire list or make it a doubly linked list.

That's a long way of saying no (thanks to @stark).

Comment: Both the tail pointer and the last node's ptr will be wrong.  So the correct answer is just "no"

Comment: @stark If the tail points to the last node you'd `free(tail);` But there is no way to update tail after this without traversing the entire list.

Comment: @stark I see what you're saying. I read "delete" as simply freeing the memory. But to truly remove the node you would have to traverse the whole list. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in order for this to work without making it a doubly linked list, you could have the tail's *next pointer point to the head of the list, then traverse through it till you reach the node before the tail. once there you can NULL its *next pointer which would essentially detach the original tail from the list. you would then set the tail to the current node, then finally free the original tail.

```
void del_last(Node **head, Node **tail) {
    struct node *new_head = *head;
    struct node *current = *tail;

    current->next = head;

    while(current-> != *tail)    //getting the node right before the original tail
    {
         current = current->next
    }

    current->next = NULL;   //detaches original tail form list

    free(**tail);   //gets rid of original tail
    **tail = current;   // sets current node to tail pointer
}
```